# How to use reduce in this algorithm?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

```
    /*
     When consecutive values come into the array, 
     delete and count the number

      I want to this result
      count = 4 // [1, 1, 3, 3]
      array = [4, 2, 4]
    */
    
    let count = 0;
    let array = [4, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4]
 
    array.reduce((acc, cur) => {
      if (acc[acc.length - 1] === cur) {
        acc.pop()
        count += 2
      } 
        // this part
        else return acc.concat(cur)
    }, [])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLejW.png)

I don't know why the above error occurs when I write 'else' word in the code
and

I want the result in the comment. How is it good to solve it?

Comment: What should be the return value for [4, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 3]?

Comment: Have a look at how [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) works and in and in particular the `accumulator`. If you don't return a value from your callback (which is the case when your if-branch is entered), the next iteration your `accumulator` will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the result of your `reduce` operation and also return the accumulator inside your `if` block too for next iterations:

```js
/*
  I want to this result
  count = 4 // [1, 1, 3, 3]
  array = [4, 2, 4]
*/

let count = 0;
let array = [4, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4]
 
array = array.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (acc[acc.length - 1] === cur) {
    acc.pop()
    count += 2;
    return acc;
  } else {
    return acc.concat(cur);
  } 
}, []);

console.log({count, array});
```

Answer (score 2):

You forget to return acc

```js
let count = 0;
let array = [4, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4]
     
let result = array.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (acc[acc.length - 1] === cur) {
    acc.pop()
    count += 2
    return acc;
  } 
  else return acc.concat(cur)
}, [])
        
console.log(count);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could go s slightly different way by looking only to the values and the collecting of singel values.

The final `count` derivd from the lengths of both arrays.

```js
const
    array = [4, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4],
    result = array.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        if (acc[acc.length - 1] === cur) acc.pop();
        else acc.push(cur);
        return acc;
    }, []),
    count = array.length - result.length;

console.log(count);
console.log(result);
```